# sonar report failed while compiling build

Tags: maven, unit-testing, bamboo

The bamboo build is failed while compiling the sonar report even We added dependencies packages in pom.xml file. Might be this issue related to dependencies?

**Bamboo goal command**

-U clean test -Dtest.profile=integration

**Bamboo error log**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project auth-server-admin-webapp: There are test failures.
 [ERROR] Please refer to /datafiles/itdept/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/ASA-ASA-IT/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: You're tests are failing...So i would suggest to check for failing tests...and maybe you can add `--fail-at-end` to run everything instead of failing at the first tests...Furthermore why have you added `-U`?

Comment: I don't know that. -U clean test 
-Dtest.profile=integration 
-DBASE_URL=http://xxxxxxxx:9090 --fail-at-end

Comment: An initial my team has configured like that

Comment: I have added into build it with --fail-at-end then it works fine. I don't know how it is working.